# In IE, what's the difference between File->Save As and document.execCommand('SaveAs')?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

In IE, what's the difference between <kbd>File->Save As</kbd> (pic1) and `document.execCommand('SaveAs')` (pic2)?

The popup window seems to be the same with just some minor differences.

pic1 (<kbd>File->Save As</kbd>):

[image]

pic2 (`document.execCommand('SaveAs')`):

[image]

(IE version 10)

Answer (score 1):

With <kbd>File -> Save As</kbd> you're saving the entirety of the web page that's been loaded (including any assets (CSS files, images, etc.)). This is why the *save as type* here is set to "Webpage, complete".

With `document.execCommand('SaveAs')` you're saving the HTML `document` specifically without any of the assets, which is why the *save as type* in this case is "HTML File".